Putting markers on an image
I divided the screen into two parts so that I can show another essay - And I need to add markers with matching colors on both of them so that people can the references.
The problem is after I move the red marker it creates a very big gap between the green marker and the following text.
(OPEN IT IN FULL SCREEN TO SEE WHAT I MEAN)
I think I've tried everything I learned so far in html and css - And I don't think I get how to fix this. Thank you!
This is the code:


body{
  overflow-x:hidden ;
}
.drag-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x:hidden ;
}

.panel-one {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.panel-two {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.m-aquamarine {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.m-red {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 550px;

  vertical-align: text-top;

  width: 320px;
  height: 14.8px;
  background-color:red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
<body>
  <div class="drag-container">
    <div class="panel-one">
      <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/Wi25Ezsw.png" width="100%">

      <p>
      <span class="m-aquamarine">
        Hey Gustaf! Azng sjczv zncsn djfandz czns!!
      </span>

      <span class="m-red"></span>
        Dzns kds fdskcznc eandz ncz!?!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-two">
      <div class="container">

        <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/Wi25Ezsw.png" ; style="display: block; width: 100%;">

        <p>Hello there! Erkdfs dms djc zc dnacjzz csjdasc!!</p>
</body>



